# Como preencher uma lista C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, array

Preciso de um recurso semelhante ao apresentado abaixo:

```
     email ListaEmail = new email();
     … 
     while …
     {
       email Email = new email();
       Email.email1 = adoDR["email"].ToString();
       Email.tipo = adoDR["tipo"].ToString();
       ListaEmail.Add(Email); 
     }
```

Porém, a lista não aceita o método Add().

Então tentei declarar o array com o número de registros:

```
email[] ListaEmail = new email[nRegistros];
```

e preencher os campos de cada registro.
Porém, cada elemento de ListaEmail é criado com conteúdo null, e não com a estrutura e ocorre erro em tempo de execução ao se tentar atribuir o conteúdo

```
ListaEmail [Cont].email1 = adoDR["email"].ToString();
```

O código está abaixo:

```
public static email[] Func_RelatorEmail(Guid IdRelator)
{
  try
  {
   string sql = "SELECT Relator_Email.IdRelator, Relator_Email.EmailId, Email.email, Email.tipo, Email.tipoSpecified "
                      + "FROM Relator_Email INNER JOIN Email ON Relator_Email.EmailId = Email.EmailId "
                      + "WHERE(Relator_Email.IdRelator='" + IdRelator + "')";

    string connString = ClsParametros.Conexao;
    SqlConnection adoConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    adoConn.Open();
    SqlCommand adoCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, adoConn);
    SqlDataReader adoDR = adoCmd.ExecuteReader();

    // contar o numero de registros
    int nRegistros = 0;
    while (adoDR.Read())
    { ++nRegistros; }

    // criar o objeto com o numero de registros 
    email[] ListaEmail = new email[nRegistros];

    if (nRegistros > 0)
    {
      adoDR.Close();
      adoDR = adoCmd.ExecuteReader();

      int Cont = 0;
      while (adoDR.Read())
      {
         ListaEmail[Cont].email1 = adoDR["email"].ToString();
         ListaEmail[Cont].tipo = adoDR["tipo"].ToString();
         Cont++;
      }
   }
   adoDR.Close();
   adoDR.Dispose();
   adoCmd.Dispose();
   adoConn.Close();
   adoConn.Dispose();

    return ListaEmail;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
  }
}
```

Com certeza, não é a forma mais eficiente para se resolver o problema.
Porém, como o controle não terá utilização muito intensa e tenho muito pouco tempo para resolver o problema, tentei dessa forma.
Tem alguma sugestão para resolver esse problema?

Obrigado!

Paulo

Comment: Sua lista não é uma lista, por isso ela não aceita o método `Add`. `email ListaEmail = new email();` está errado, deveria ser: `IList<email> ListaEmail = new List<email>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Preciso de um recurso semelhante ao apresentado abaixo
>
> ```
> email ListaEmail = new email();     
> while …
> {
>     email Email = new email();
>     Email.email1 = adoDR["email"].ToString();
>     Email.tipo = adoDR["tipo"].ToString();
>     ListaEmail.Add(Email); 
> }
> ```

Você precisa declarar uma lista, não um `email`.

Apenas troque a declaração **`email ListaEmail = new email();`** para **`List<email> ListaEmail = new List<email>();`**

---

```
List<email> ListaEmail = new List<email>();     
while(condicao)
{
    email Email = new email();
    Email.email1 = adoDR["email"].ToString();
    Email.tipo = adoDR["tipo"].ToString();
    ListaEmail.Add(Email); 
}
```

Comment: Ajustei o controle para utilizar List, porém, essa função deve alimentar os dados de um Web Service, cuja estrutura tem a definição que tem um conjunto email[].
Então aparece o erro 

 Cannot implicitly type 'System.Collection.Generic.List<email>' to email[]
 
O caminho seria converter List<email> para email[]? Se sim, como se efetua a conversão.
Pois esse é um exemplo simplificado, mas precisarei efetuar muitas outras estruturas no projeto.

Obrigado!
Paulo

Comment: @PauloYatsuzuka na lista, faça `ListEmail.ToArray()` (LINQ) para converter a lista num array.

Comment: @PauloYatsuzuka Exatamente isso que o Omni citou. Inclua o namespace `System.Linq` para poder este método.

Comment: Segui a orientação declarando como List<> e deu certo.
Somente precisei colocar no final
    return ListaEmail.ToArray();   Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esse problema você deve usar a classe `List<T>`.
A classe `List<T>` é genérica, onde `T` é o tipo do qual você quer que a sua lista seja. No seu caso, `List<Email>`.
Dê uma olhada nessa [apostila da Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/trabalhando-com-listas/), acho que lhe ajudará bastante! :-)